# CGAL integration with CMake using deb package

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal, find-package

I want to make a script that uses the CGAL Library having it installed only using the .deb package. (Using: `sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev`).

I get the following error message when I run this command : `cmake -S . -B build/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE= Release .`

[image]

I am on an ubuntu 20.04 machine with the following versions:

- g++ 9.4.0
- cmake 3.16

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
>
> project(integration)
>
> find_package(CGAL)
>
> if ( CGAL_FOUND )
>
> message("CGAL Found !")
>
> endif ( CGAL_FOUND )
>
> add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
> extract_segmentation_into_mesh_example.cpp)
>
> target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CGAL::CGAL)

I'm also able to find the directory `CGAL` in `/usr/include/`.

Comment: CGAL doesn't provide a FindCGAL.cmake. ```pkg_check_modules``` might work.

Comment: In principle, it should be detected automatically but you can try setting CGAL_DIR to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL` (`CGALConfig.cmake` should be in that directory). Try `dpkg -L libcgal-dev | grep Config` to be sure.

Comment: Interesting, the command `dpkg -L libcgal-dev | grep Config` returns the CGALConfing.cmake path, but when I do `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL` I get `cd: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL: No such file or directory`. I uninstalled libcgal-dev and installed it again the problem was solved, the directory was there. (got other compilation errors but the cmake problem is solved )